# Bokeh Old and New parameters for on_change event of a ColumnDataSource have the same value

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a ColumnDataSource that describes the data for a DataTable and I want to have an event that does something when I edit a cell in that DataTable. I setup the event on the data attribute of my ColumnDataSource and I want to get the difference between the old and new values of the attribute.

The problem is that both values are the same. How can I get the new and old values after I edit the table cell?

My code:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, DataTable, TableColumn, StringEditor
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column


def cluster_name_changed(attr, old, new):
    print(old)
    print(new)

cluster_field = 'CLUSTER'
table_clusters_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(cluster_no=[1, 2, 3]))

columns_clusters = [TableColumn(field='cluster_no',
                                title="Cluster Name",
                                editor=StringEditor())]

table_clusters = DataTable(source=table_clusters_source,
                           columns=columns_clusters,
                           width=300,
                           height=200,
                           editable=True)

table_clusters_source.on_change('data', cluster_name_changed)

curdoc().add_root(column(table_clusters))
```

and the output is (when I update the third cell from "3" to "third"):

```
{'cluster_no': [1, 2, 'third']}
{'cluster_no': [1, 2, 'third']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `old` and `new` parameters work great with simple scalar properties (i.e. whose values are numbers, strings, colors, etc). However they do not work function with ColumnDataSource, and this is a known and documented limitation (tho I don't have a reference offhand). The reason is that making `old` and `new` function for ColumnDataSource can makes things unusably slow and explode memory usage.